# Visiting the sunniest place on earth - country and city

Tags: weather-and-climate, factoids, cities, countries

This is a two parter.

Vancouver has rain for like, 9 months a year. I've been told it gets quite heavy.

If you wanted to go to the opposite extreme...

1. What country gets the most sunlight hours each year on average?
2. What city gets the most sunlight hours each year on average?

(I'm assuming the city will be in the same country as part 1, but just in case, I've separated it.

Comment: I would have said [Atacama Desert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Desert), but apparently, sunniest is not correlated with driest.

Comment: I think the sunniest place in the world may be the south pole. At least it's the driest.

Comment: 6 months a year it gets no sun at all, so I'd be surprised...also there's no city OR country there, as per title ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the Interwebz are to be believed, that would be Yuma, Arizona.

According to the [town's website](http://www.visityuma.com/climate.html) (also backed by [National Climatic Data Center](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/extremes/extreme-us-climates.html#SUN-CLOUD)), 91% of the time it's sunny there, amounting to more than 4000 hours of sunshine annually -- which apparently is also a Guiness World Record.

Other sources also concur this:

- [Current Results](http://www.currentresults.com/Weather-Extremes/sunniest-places-countries-world.php) also lists the top 10 by country and in the US. Some data on the sunniest places by month is also provided. The data seems to be compiled from [World Data Center for Meteorology](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/wdc/index.php?name=climateoftheworld).

If you are thinking of giving up travel and spending your hard-earned cash, then you might be interested in the [10 sunniest places in the US to retire](http://money.usnews.com/money/retirement/articles/2011/11/21/the-10-sunniest-places-to-retire) as well.

Also, if you [choose to believe Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2007/nov/28/weather), the sunniest patches on the Earth could actually be a patch in Sahara and an ocean region south of Hawaii and east of the island of Kiribati.

Interestingly enough, I couldn't find a reliable source for the [cloudiest place on Earth](https://www.google.com/search?q=cloudiest%20place%20on%20earth).

Comment: Yuma however is not very big (93,000 as of the 2010 census).  Phoenix and Las Vegas have almost as much sunshine as Yuma (average of 10.6 and 10.5 hours/day vs Yuma's 11.0), and would be more interesting destinations.

Comment: OP didn't mention how large it should be, his only requirements were city+country :)

Comment: If you go to Yuma I wouldn't recommend the 3:10 train.